# Moodle accessing settings from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

I'm very new to Moodle dev. I have read the basics of the API, and now started getting my hands dirty by making tinymce plugin. While doing so, I have encountered the following problem: How do I access settings.php from javascript.

I know how to access lan/en strings from javascript, I also know that in php, `$layout_string = $this->get_config('statlayout');`, will exract the setting 'statlayout'. What I want is to access `$layout_string` from JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Well I supposed there is no standard way of doing this.

- If you are making a plugin (not a subplugin for atto or tinymce), then you can simply call

  global $PAGE;
  $PAGE->requires->yui_module(
  /* frankenstyle named yui module */,
  /* entry function */
  );
- If you are making a subplugin, then you need to read the main plugin itself to discover how it calls javascript functions, for atto editor's case I think I saw the following in one of the main plugin:

  reqiure_once("plugins/$pluginname/lib.php");
  $functionname = "atto_".$puginname."params_for_js";
  call_user_func($functionname, /* some args */ );

In which case your atto subplugin's lib.php must contain a **atto_pluginname_params_for_js** function, such that pluginname is the name of your plugin.

In software engineering perspective, that is beyond disgusting. All I can say to makes things better is to abide to the software engineering principles yourself when creating your own plugin and reduce intellectual baggage for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think this is really hacky, and I wouldn't recommend it, but ***perhaps*** you could do something like this?

```
<?php
  $layout_string = $this->get_config('statlayout');
  echo "<script> var my_var = '" . $layout_string . "';</script>";
?>

<script> alert( my_var );</script>
```

If you've found another answer in the meantime, I'd be interested to know what you've come up with. :)